# Tooltip not functioning when routed to a new url path

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, tooltip

I have template php files for dates and sharing. 1 file is like this:

date-share.php:

```
<div class="date"><?php echo date('M d'); ?><span><?php echo date('Y'); ?></span></div>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="share-button"><span class="plus"></span>Share</a>
                            <!-- Tooltip -->
                            <div class="tooltip-social-network clearfix" style="margin-top: -10px">

                                <span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
                                <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
                                <span class='st_googleplus_large' displayText='Google +'></span>
                                <span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
                                <span class='st_instagram_large' displayText='Instagram Badge' st_username='mews'></span>
                                <span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
                            </div>
```

I php include it to one of my views to avoid too much clutter, instead of putting it there.

```
<?php include('templates/date-share.php')?>
```

This is how it would look like in the view when the SHARE button is clicked.

[image]

The social media icons group is just a tooltip.

However, I rerouted the view to a new url path. So I added a PHP echo base_url to all the links to maintain the root path. But I'm not sure how to apply with the php include, so I didn't add any. It still appeared but the share button can't show the tooltip anymore.

Edit: added pic for clicked SHARE without the tooltip - rerouted to a different url path

[image]

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter? if yes, then you can put your template directory under **application/views** directory and load that with `$this->view->load('template/date-share.php');` inside your main view.

Comment: @jagad89 so instead of php include? I put this?

Comment: yes, Make sure your file at following location **application/views/template/date-share.php**

Comment: @jagad89 it removed everything inside the view... T_T

Comment: What is the version of Codeigniter you using?

Comment: Sorry I made mistake. try `$this->load->view('template/date-share.php');`

Comment: Im not sure if it would be helpful, anyway it's 2.2. I'd like to add some summarization: template/date-share.php can be seen in my view - however, the tooltip does not function. This might be because i have routed my view to a new path by editing it in the route.php. So yeah, I don't know how to fix the problem but I'm guessing that would be the cause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81067/discussion-between-jagad89-and-hazelvan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `view` method inside view to load other view/partials.

Make sure your `date-share.php` under following path `application/views/template/date-share.php'

Now inside your main view load your `date-share.php` as below.

`$this->load->view('template/date-share.php');`